# Should i use 'conda init' before opening jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I recently installed anaconda3 in ubuntu on default location. I didn't want base env to run every time i open terminal, so i used `conda config --set auto_activate_base False`.

To open jupyter notebook, i need to use `source /home/<path to anaconda3>/anaconda3/bin/activate`. Now, anaconda documentation specifically says to use `conda init` after it.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

But without using the `conda init` command i can directly open jupyter notebook (or anaconda). Should i use `conda init` or bypass it?

Comment: can you link to the part in the conda documentation?

Comment: well, actually the  `source /home/<path to anaconda3>/anaconda3/bin/activate` is to activate an env. You can use jupyter without an env, if you call the jupyter from the terminal in the dir where the jupyter installation is. Or set up a path to the jupyter Installation and start jupyter using that. Basically jupyter and conda can live without one another.